# Credit card company forgot to reflect a returned payment in my balance. It only showed up after I closed the account. Am I obligated to pay?

Tags: credit-card, debt, australia

I made a payment about 9 months ago to pay off the balance of my credit card. For some reason the payment never went through. I didn't notice. The credit card company also didn't notice that the funds never came through and gave me credit for paying off my balance even though the funds never actually left my bank account. After closing the card, they audited my account and discovered that I owed them the money and are asking for it. Am I legally obligated to pay?

Comment: If they didn't reflect a refund until after the account was closed,  would you be happy with them keeping _your_ money? More directly, closing the account does not invalidate your contract obliging you to pay for all charges.

Comment: You used their money to buy stuff = you have a legal and moral obligation to pay them back.

Comment: Of course you're obligated to pay.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't mentioned the country. As a general premise, you own them money and the fact that the account was closed has no bearing on the fact that you own them money. My suggestion would be pay them off.

Comment: Country is Australia

Comment: Issuing a statement reflecting the payment being posted, and allowing the account to be closed, doesn't result in estoppel?

Comment: "Closing" the account just stops more charges from being made to it. You are still under exactly the same terms regarding paying off any remaining balance, including accumulating interest charges. The account is not actually "closed" until the balance becomes and remains zero -- just "in the process of closing".After all these years, there's zero chance that any bank would allow a loss from such a common situation. And, again, you'd be demanding it work this way if it was a late credit rather than late charge.